# Angular2 modular view

Tags: angular, modularity, angular2-template

How to create a modular view using Angular2? When I click on a menu item I want to update the container and leave my menu, just update some classes. How can I achieve this?

Any resources available on this topic?

-

*UPDATE*

When I click on a menu item to go to a different page in my app. For instance, go from 'home' to 'manage products'. I want to show the 'Manage products' context, but not reload the menu (and other components that don't need to reload)

Comment: This question is quite vague. Can you please add some code that shows what you try to accomplish? I guess you are looking for routing. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer see my edit, maybe its more clear now

Comment: Yup, router is what you're looking for, see the linked tutorial above and http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/16/routing-in-angular-2.html

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer exactly what I was looking for! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Angular2 routing feature allows you to link views to particular paths. This can be defined for a specific component. The `RouterOutlet` directive corresponds to a placeholder that Angular dynamically fills with the component associated with the route.

This means that elements around can remain the same.

Here is a sample:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <!-- The menu block -->
    <div>
      My menu
    </div>

    <!-- The dynamic content area -->
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
  directives: [ ROUTER_DIRECTIVES ]
})
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/products', component: ProductListComponent, name: 'Products' }
  { path: '/products/:id', component: ProductDetailsComponent, name: 'Product'}
])
export class AppComponent {
  (...)
}
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry